# Get all row columns from SQLite cursor into an object

Tags: java, android, sqlite, object, android-cursor

I have a cursor reading a SQLite DB and getting a lot of columns, I am storing these columns in a lot of arrays

```
private ArrayList<String> column1,column2,column3,column4, ... column n;
public getCursorData(Cursor cursor){
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            column1.add(Cursor.getString("column1"));
            column2.add(Cursor.getString("column2"));
            column3.add(Cursor.getString("column3"));
            column4.add(Cursor.getString("column4"));
            ...
            columnn.add(Cursor.getString("columnN"));
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

I am looking for a way to store them in a single object (or array, or List, or something), but I can not figure it how to do it

```
private Object[] object;
public getCursorData(Cursor cursor){
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        int i=0;
        do{
            for(int f=0;f<cursor.getColumnCount();f++){
                object[i].put(cursor.getColumnName(i), cursor.getString(i)); // I don't know what I am doing!
            }
            i++;
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

A different attempt using arrays, where each column is an integer number.

```
private String[][] data;
public getCursorData(Cursor cursor){
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        int i=0;
        do{
            for(int f=0;f<cursor.getColumnCount();f++){
                data[i][f]=cursor.getString(f); // this is line 30
            }
            i++;
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

This last attempt fails throwing the following error `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array` on line 30 (I marked this line in a comment on the code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can create a Custom Object to map those values.. Something like:

```
public class TableData {
    public String mColumn1;
    public String mColumn2;
    public String mColumn3;
    public String mColumn4;
    public String mColumn5;
}

public ArrayList<TableData> getCursorData(Cursor cursor) {

    ArrayList<TableData> resultList = new ArrayList();

    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            TableData row = new TableData();
            row.mColumn1 = Cursor.getString("column1");
            row.mColumn2 = Cursor.getString("column2");
            row.mColumn3 = Cursor.getString("column3");
            ...
            resultList.add(row);
        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return resultList;
}
```

Edit:

If you want to keep your approach, you should:

```
private String[][] data;

public void getCursorData(Cursor cursor) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        data = new String[cursor.getCount()][]; // You have to instantiate your bi-dimensional array
        int i = 0;
        do {
            data[i] = new String[cursor.getColumnCount()];
            for (int f = 0; f < cursor.getColumnCount(); f++) {
                data[i][f] = cursor.getString(f);
            }
            i++;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this idea, but, is there any way to avoid repeating `row.mColumnN = Cursor.getString("columnN");`? doing a for or map or something? I will try the second method and let you know.

Comment: The second method works for me, but I also had to declare the second dimension length (`data=new String[cursor.getCount()][8];`), thank you for your help.